# simple example/tutorial showing how to send Lync messages from a console app

Tags: lync-2010

I have code I wrote using xmpp to all users to communicate with my code through instant messages. Since I'm in a Microsoft shop now I'd like to convert this code over to use Microsoft Lync. Problem is all the samples I've found only show you how to build thick clients with a ui. I am building a library that will be called by code running long processes so there will be no user or UI.

Can anyone point me to some good examples or tutorials that will get me to the point where I can login to an account and send/receive messages to individuals/groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lync 2010, you may have to create an UCMA application and expose the interfaces which you want.

For Lync 2013, you can take advantage of UCWA API. You can find more details on this [MSDN Channel](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Lync-Developer-Roundtable-UCWA-Overview).

Comment: I will try this out, thank you so much. It sounds more and more like 2013 has a lot of features/support we can't live without.